# Generic override method in in Polymorphic object

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, overriding

I'm having trouble with the syntax of using a generic override method in a polymorphic base class.

Here is the basic architecture, which is used for a reporting engine; I have two virtual methods in a base class and a ton of objects that are derived from the base class and they override those methods.

In client code, a report factory object is called that instantiates one of those objects based on a string passed in along with an array of objects used as parameters. The string name of the method comes from the database and are in a multiselect list so the user can select any number of reports to run.

Right now the requirement is to create PDF documents, and that was the easy one to do since that generic method has a single known type.  What I would like to do is to expand the usefulness of this and return a list of any type.

Here are the signatures of my virtual methods.  The first one which is strongly typed I get to work perfectly, the second one, I have issues with.  Here they are:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Virtual method to run report from a Word mail merge template
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Template">Word mail merge template name</param>
    /// <returns>PDF Document</returns>
    public virtual PdfDocument RunReportPDFOutFromWordTemplate( string TemplateName )
    {
        try
        {
            return new PdfDocument();
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Virtual method to run report outputting a generic list
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual List<T> RunReportListOut<T>()
    {
        try
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Then in my code I invoke the object by calling my ReportFactory Class.  First the ReportFactory class and then the invocation code:

```
    public static class ReportFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get an object from the Report Factory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ObjectName">Name of the Object</param>
    /// <param name="ParamList">List of parameters the object constructor is expecting</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ReportBase GetObject( string ObjectName, object[] ParamList )
    {
        try
        {
            return (ReportBase)Activator.CreateInstance( Type.GetType( Utils.GetCurrentNamespaceName() + "." + ObjectName ), ParamList );
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Now for the invocation code:

```
                        ParamList = new object[] { r.Name, r.MethodPointer, this.dpStartDate.SelectedDate, this.dpEndDate.SelectedDate, this.AppData.ActivePatient };
                    rb = ReportFactory.GetObject( r.MethodPointer, ParamList );

                    PdfDocument pdfDoc = rb.RunReportPDFOutFromWordTemplate( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "ReportTemplateLocation" ].ToString() + r.MethodPointer + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "ReportTemplateType" ].ToString() );
```

The code for the method that works is not really relevant here and I don't want to waste anyone's time by posting it.  It works for what I need it to do.

The issue is I would like to be able to return a list using the same report factory.  When I override my method, I get the following error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FMCNA_Model.Cycle>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Cycle>`

Here is the overridden code and a helper method:

```
    public override List<Cycle> RunReportListOut<Cycle>()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Cycle> CycleList = this.GetCycleList();
            return CycleList;
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private List<Cycle> GetCycleList()
    {
        try
        {
            return Cycle.PatientForDateRange( this.CurrentPatient.PatientIDInternal, this.StartDate, this.EndDate );
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I'm stumped here how to do this.  Sorry this question is so long, I thought it would be best to get everything out to focus on the override syntax.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Why do you have pointless try/catch blocks all over your code? Get rid of all of them - your code will be cleaner and easier to read. Likewise, why bother with your helper method? Just move all of that into `RunReportListOut`, given that it doesn't do anything else...

Answer (score 1):

As SLaks says, you've got a problem of trying to declare a generic virtual method using a *type parameter* called `T` - but then you're trying to override it with another generic method using `Cycle` as the type parameter. That's really not what you meant. A generic method means the *caller* gets to specify the type argument - whereas presumably you *only* want to return a `List<Cycle>`.

I strongly suspect you should have a generic *type*, with a method declaration which uses that type parameter. For example:

```
public abstract class Report<T>
{
    public abstract List<T> RunReportListOut();
}
```

then

```
public class CycleReport : Report<Cycle>
{
    public override List<T> RunReportListOut()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you *want* to have two types, it would be cleaner to name them differently... and then you'll need to add a conversion in your method. Alternatively, just collapse the two types to one, which is likely to be much cleaner.

Additionally, as I noted in a comment, you should remove your try/catch blocks. None of them have any benefit, and they clutter up your code - currently within the bodies of your methods you have a total of 6 lines of "body" code, and 35 lines of pointless try/catch. Once you've removed those, it becomes more obvious that your `GetCycleList` helper method is pointless, too. You can just write:

```
public override List<Cycle> RunReportListOut()
{
    return Cycle.PatientForDateRange(this.CurrentPatient.PatientIDInternal,
                                     this.StartDate, this.EndDate);
}
```

Comment: They are the same type.  Structurally, I have all of the report code in a folder in the model called Reports and the Cycle object is in the model.  Any thoughts how to make them the same?

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, good call. Will edit into a more sensible shape.

Comment: @SLaks: Could you have a look and see whether this now looks reasonable to you?

Comment: Jon, you are right about getting rid of the extra method.  I'm working with trial code and trying to do the same thing different ways to isolate the problem.  I originally did what you suggested and thought structuring the call differently might shed light on my problem, you know shake the bushes a little to try to learn something.

Comment: Jon, I will look at your approach and I do thank you for your suggestion.  It will take me a little time to absorb this.  I'd like to see what approaches others may come up with too as I am very new to this level of coding.

Comment: Yes; this is probably exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

```
public override List<Cycle> RunReportListOut<Cycle>()
```

This creates a regular generic method, with a type parameter that happens to be named `Cycle`
It's no different from `public override List<T> RunReportListOut<T>()`; the type parameter can still be any type.

What you're trying to do is completely impossible; you cannot override a generic method with a non-generic method.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, you are saying this should work, but I can't get it to work.  Any thoughts why?

Comment: @MikeMalter: No.  It _cannot_ work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: @MikeMalter: See my answer *alongside* this one for a suggestion of how you might want to proceed.